# How to get FB access token when user have given some permission and denied some permission using Facebook C# sdk 5.4.1.0

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-login

I'm facing this issue on Window Phone 7.8. I'm not able to get access token when user give some permissions to my app and some skips or denied.

For e.g I have asked user to give these permissions `"user_about_me", "offline_access", "publish_stream", "user_photos", "publish_checkins", "photo_upload", "email", "manage_pages"` but user only given permission to  "user_about_me". Then facebook should return access token but it navigated to this url `"http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied&state#_=_"` with in following error in FacebookOAuthResult `Error`=access_denied, `ErrorDescription`=Permissions error, `ErrorReason`=user_denied

Comment: Just info - `offline_access` has been depreciated.